# How do I extract and print both these named capture groups in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, named-captures

I want to print **both** the `gclid` and the `session` named captures, but my regex is quitting as soon as it matches the gclid:

```
echo '"https://example.com/foo/?gclid=abc1234gef76786" session="765dsfsdf7657657khkjh"' | perl -nE '/(?<gclid>gclid=[^&"#\s]*)|(?<session>session=.*)/&&say"gclid: $+{gclid} session: $+{session}"'
```

Results in:

```
gclid: gclid=abc1234gef76786 session:
```

But I want:

```
gclid: gclid=abc1234gef76786 session: session="765dsfsdf7657657khkjh"
```

The `echo` is just an example line from one of millions that will be processed.

Comment: You are performing an "or" so it found `gclid` and quit; just like you told it to...

Comment: Thanks, I get that. Just not sure what the combining operator should be.

Comment: Then you can use something like [`\?gclid=(?<gclid>.*?)".*?session="(?<session>.*?)"`](https://regex101.com/r/7dG3P3/1). This of course works for the exact example you provided so if other lines have deviations from your example's format then it would be in your best interest to provide multiple examples and explain what should and what should not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using the `|` operator so the regex matching stops when any of the two patterns matches. You can use `.*` in between the two patterns instead. Put `\b` before `session` to ensure word boundary:

```
perl -nE '/(?<gclid>gclid=[^&"#\s]*).*(?<session>\bsession=.*)/&&say"gclid: $+{gclid} session: $+{session}"'
```